# How to get a value from DateTime picker in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use Material-UI in order to create a DateTime picker. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/213lywm66n) is my demo code.

I added `console.log` to the function `handleChange` in order to see a current selected value. However, the value does not change when I use DatTime picker:

```
handleChange = name => event => {
  const target = event.target;
  const name = target.name;
  console.log("plannedDep", this.state.plannedDep)
  this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I added the state value as default value to plannedDep. `value={this.state.plannedDep}`
2. I changed the onChange this way: `onChange={(event) => this.handleChange("plannedDep", event)}`. Going by your code, `onChange={this.handleChange("plannedDep")}` the onchange you have will be fired as soon as the component is mounted and for every state/prop change resulting in unnecessary renders.

```
<TextField
  id="datetime-local"
  label="Next appointment"
  type="datetime-local"
  onChange={(event) => this.handleChange("plannedDep", event)}
  value={this.state.plannedDep}
  className={classes.textField}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
 />
```

3. We have to check the value after setting the state, not before setting it. Im doing the check in the setState's callback, and it shows the updated value to me.

```
handleChange = (name, event) => {
  const target = event.target; // Do we need this?(unused in the function scope)!
  this.setState({
    [name]: event.target.value
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.plannedDep)
    // Prints the new value.
  });
};
```

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Cool! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You override the `name` argument passed to the method `handleChange` inside that method, doing `const name = target.name;`, so when you set back the state at the end:

```
this.setState({
  [name]: event.target.value
})
```

You are not setting the expected `plannedDep`.

You can fix it in two ways:

1) Set the state directly through:

```
this.setState({
  plannedDep: event.target.value
})
```

2) Add a name attribute to your `TextField` so that `target.name` will be the value of the name attribute of your TextField which fired the event:

```
<TextField
  id="datetime-local"
  name="plannedDep" // see here!
  label="Next appointment"
  type="datetime-local"
  onChange={this.handleChange("plannedDep")}
  defaultValue="2017-05-24T10:30"
  className={classes.textField}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true
  }}
/>
```

Here the [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0yn6l38xkp)

Comment: Thanks. When I start typing, console.log returns values like `0201-05-24T10:35` instead of `2018-05-24T10:35`. It seems to update a value on each touch of a DateTime picker and picks unfinished value for some reason.

Comment: that's because you print the previous value in the state, not the current one, you should do `console.log("plannedDep", event.target.value);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is your `onChange` handler. If you are passing a value into the `onChange` you must initialize it in a callback.
Try changing your `onChange` to `onChange={() => this.handleChange("plannedDep")}`